# Falha na tarefa SrcSet0 (Carregando) na origem MICROSOFT_EXCEL ODBC

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odbc, xls

Bom dia, estou tentando configurar o oracle data integrator para fazer leitura de uma planilha do excel nos formatos xls e xlsx, porem estou com problemas e não encontro uma solução! ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configurei desta forma o ODBC:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E testando a topologia separada me retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei pela internet e não encontrei nada que me ajudasse...
O que devo fazer?